# Problems with cookies and TortoiseSVN

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, tortoise-svn

I use Google Chrome and I'm constantly logged off from my Google Account, but also from other websites.

The other problem is that also my [TortoiseSVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) installation lose its user/password setting.

I already check each Google Chrome setting related to *cookies* deletion. Nothing helps me.

All these problems started about a month ago when I updated Windows 10.

How I can stop this confusing situation when daily I must set up all my access login/password?

Comment: If you backup your current Google profile, delete the profile and allow Chrome to recreate your profile does that resolve the problem?

Comment: Are you using any PC cleaning software? They tend to remove any cookie-related info, so you can loose that data

Comment: TortoiseSVN does not use cookies.

Comment: @Carles as far as I remeber only ESET, will check deeply when I be again on this computer

Comment: @bahrep I know that SVN does not use cookies, but I can connect this issues , they are related somehow.

Comment: Have you done full AV and antimalware scans of your system? Have you removed unneeded Chrome extensions (or all of them)? Have you done any sort of Windows 10 system clean up and health scans and such? Have you run chkdsk for file system corruption and see if it's able to fix up anything it finds? Start with the basics and rule those things out first just in case. Is this a machine that is domain connected to a company network where policies may be applying to Chrome or the Windows 10 OS? Have you confirmed the Windows 10 OS is fully updated Windows Updates as of now?

Comment: Check the settings on this post: https://www.minitool.com/news/chrome-keeps-signing-me-out.html and maybe this post too just in case https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-chrome-keeps-logging-me-out-issue/ but I'd check those other things I mentioned first too with AV and antimalware scans, remove Chrome extensions and all that, and run some disk cleanup commands. Also the very first comment about a corrupt Chrome profile is not a bad idea too as it could be that. Please ensure people understand what all you have tried and not just "many things that have not helped"--be clear here for the best help!

Comment: Try to toggle off all your extensions in `chrome://extensions/`.

Comment: at `chrome://extensions/` I have only `Adobe Acrobat` and `Google Documenst offline` I remove them both. Will see if that change anything.

Comment: I will do all @DrinkSomePimpJuiceIT proposals tomorrow as for now I must observe if `harrymc` solutions give any results.

Comment: @MichałLipok Sure, I suggested removing unneeded Chrome extensions in the comment before Harry. He merely gave you the Chrome URL shortcut to get to those quickly (for disabling or removing) without the need to look it up if you were not already familiar with that. In any case, hopefully you find a solution that works to fix your problem which is the important part to me.

Comment: Current state after removal of `Adobe Acrobat` and `Google Documents offline` .... looks good. few time restart browser, few time restart computer. 1 time I have to provide password for TortoisSVN. Will look 1 next day without taking further action, just observing. btw. as for now I Agree that @DrinkSomePimpJuiceIT was the first who give the tip about extensions. Will see in next few days if he win the bounty.

Comment: Windows is fully updated. `Is this a machine that is domain connected to a company network where policies may be applying to Chrome or the Windows 10 OS?` No domain.

Comment: Full scan starts 1 per week. No problem with ESET Security.

Comment: as for now situation is still fine (after extension removal) but nothing changed with tortoise

Comment: @MichałLipok See the comment in my answer below for additional steps to take for the TortoiseSVN issue. If that helps, let me know and I'll add to answer with more detail and reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General Troubleshooting

Consider the following in no particular order...

- Run full antivirus and antimalware scans of your system
- Remove unneeded Chrome extensions or all of them (e.g. `chrome://extensions/`)
- Ensure all the latest Windows Updates are downloaded, installed, and any correlated reboots have completed too
- Run Windows 10 system health checks and cleanup scans

  > ```
  > SFC /SCANNOW
  > DISM.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
  > DISM.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /SPSuperseded
  > DISM.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
  > ```
  >
  > **PowerShell Elevated**
  >
  > ```
  > Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\*' | % {
  >     New-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -Name StateFlags0001 -Value 2 -PropertyType DWord -Force
  > };
  > Start-Process -FilePath CleanMgr.exe -ArgumentList '/sagerun:1'
  > ```
- Run `chkdsk` for file system corruption  (e.g. admin elevated `chkdsk C: /f /r /x`)

I'd start with the basics here and rule these things out first just in case.

---

If this machine is domain connected to a company network where policies may be applying to Chrome or the Windows 10 OS, you may need to work with your IT administrators to help troubleshoot and resolve.

## Additional resources for other things to try

- [How Do I Stop Google Chrome From Signing Me Out](https://www.minitool.com/news/chrome-keeps-signing-me-out.html)
- [Top 7 Ways to Fix Chrome Keeps Log­ging Me Out Issue](https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-chrome-keeps-logging-me-out-issue/)
- Rebuild a new Chrome profile
- Rebuild a new Windows User account profile

Comment: @MichałLipok ... Have you already `TortoiseSVN settings` -> `Saved Data` -> `Clear` **Authentication data**, and check `AllowAuthSave` is set to `true` in `TortoiseSVN settings` -> `Advanced`?  Or how about in `General` ->  `Subversion Configuration File` -> `Edit` and make sure `password-stores = windows-cryptoapi` is enabled by removing `#` at the beginning of its line. Before sure `store-passwords = yes` and `store-auth-creds = yes` and remove the `#` at the beginning of its line.

Comment: You answered first. Your reply regarding extensions in chrome helped me. I cannot confirm if your Tortoise answer was helpful, as I solved the problem with "Pilar ツ". But you were the first. Your answer. It is the most complementary. You win the bounty prize.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that resolved the same problem with my authorization in Google Chrome and TortoiseSVN.

1. Solution to Google Chrome:
   Copy this URL:`chrome://settings/syncSetup` and paste it to your browser. The next step is to click to "Review your synced data" and next click to "CLEAR DATA". Restart your browser and log in to your profile in Google Chrome.
2. Solution to TortoiseSVN:
   Delete the folders from this localization `%APPDATA%\subversion\auth\`
   Folders will stay created again when you log in to TortoiseSVN again. I restart my computer many times and the user name and password are still saved.

Comment: Will check this soon

Comment: About "CLEAR DATA" I worry about if they be synchronized again ? And I must to say that I use this google account on 3 devices (PC, Notebook, Android Phone). So I wondering how the "CLEAR DATA" will interferee with other devices ?

Comment: I found this information on this [site](https://www.webnots.com/5-ways-to-fix-google-chrome-sync-issues/) about "CLEAR DATA: they write only this: "Remember, resetting sync will delete the data on the server. However, the data on your local device will remain untouched. So you can re-sync your local data again to the server." When I did this I didn't lose any data for my account.

Comment: As nobody else said nothing about Tortoise problem, and taking to the account fact that again I was asked for credentials/authentification I checked yours solutions with deleting ``%APPDATA%\subversion\auth\`` . Of course I make a copy `auth - 2021-02-04 - working after re-auth` to have an oportunity to compare in any case.